# RcppEigen STL Iterators

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to apply a lambda expression to columns of an `RcppEigen` `MatrixXd`. I found the following code on the Eigen webpages:

```
Matrix3i m = Matrix3i::Random();
cout << "Here is the initial matrix m:" << endl << m << endl;
int i = -1;
for(auto c: m.colwise()) {
  c *= i;
  ++i;
}
cout << "Here is the matrix m after the for-range-loop:" << endl << m << endl;
auto cols = m.colwise();
auto it = std::find_if(cols.cbegin(), cols.cend(),
                       [](Matrix3i::ConstColXpr x) { return x.squaredNorm() == 0; });
cout << "The first empty column is: " << distance(cols.cbegin(),it) << endl;
```

It works when I include the native `#include <Eigen/Dense>`. However, it does not work using `#include <RcppEigen.h>` on a Matrix originating in R.

Has anybody else encountered this problem or has a solution? Thank you.

Here is the original code:

```
#define EIGEN_PERMANENTLY_DISABLE_STUPID_WARNINGS
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

using Eigen::Map;                   // 'maps' rather than copies 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;              // variable size matrix, double precision

Eigen::Vector3d F(const Eigen::Vector3d &column)
{
  Eigen::Vector3d abc;
  abc << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0;
  return column + abc;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void myfun(Map<MatrixXd> myMatrix)
{
  
  std::cout << "Before\n";
  std::cout << myMatrix << "\n";
  
  auto myMatrixColwise = myMatrix.colwise();
  
  std::transform(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column) {
    return F(column);
  });
  
  std::cout << "After\n";
  std::cout << myMatrix << "\n";
  
}

/***R
set.seed(123)
X = matrix(runif(3*3, 0, 1), 3, 3)
myfun(X)
*/
```

Here is the error message I get

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("src/colwise_lambda.cpp")
colwise_lambda.cpp:25:34: error: no member named 'begin' in 'Eigen::VectorwiseOp<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0>, 0>, 0>'
  std::transform(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column) {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
colwise_lambda.cpp:25:59: error: no member named 'end' in 'Eigen::VectorwiseOp<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0>, 0>, 0>'
  std::transform(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column) {
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
colwise_lambda.cpp:25:82: error: no member named 'begin' in 'Eigen::VectorwiseOp<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0>, 0>, 0>'
  std::transform(myMatrixColwise.begin(), myMatrixColwise.end(), myMatrixColwise.begin(), [](const auto &column) {
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [colwise_lambda.o] Error 1
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include" -I"/Users/sphache/RProjects/rcppEigenTests/src" -I"/Users/sphache/RProjects/rcppEigenTests/src/../inst/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c colwise_lambda.cpp -o colwise_lambda.o
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("src/colwise_lambda.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What does "not work" mean? Compiler error, runtime error, unexpected results? If you have any error message, please post it here as well.

Comment: Hi there, sure, please see below. thank you.

Comment: Hi Christine, please edit your original question rather than writing an answer. That's the wrong place for such things.